# How to change character encoding of a PDO/SQLite connection in PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm having a little problem with a php-gtk app that keeps running into non-utf8 strings, I had found that the problem is in the database connection, even when the database is supposed to be in UTF-8.

I had tried with the "SET CHARACTER SET utf8"(MySQL way) and the "SET NAMES UTF8" and nothing happen (there isn't any information about none of this commands in the "[Query Language Understood by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html)
" page either, so I'm not surprised about that).

PD: Maybe the connection is already in UTF-8 and the data isn't, but if there is a way to change the connection encoding this question would still be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can tell, [SQLite only has one setting for charset](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding), which is on a per-database level. You can't change the encoding on the connection.

The C API has [two different ways](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) of opening a connection, either as UTF-8 or UTF-16. I would expect PHP's SQLite module (And thus PDO) to simply use the UTF-8 version. If that's correct, I would expect that a SQLite connection is always UTF-8. This means that you ought to manually encode/decode strings with [utf8_encode](http://docs.php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-encode.php)/[utf8_decode](http://docs.php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-decode.php).

Also see: [`http://www.alberton.info/dbms_charset_settings_explained.html`](http://www.alberton.info/dbms_charset_settings_explained.html)

Comment: I had Discovered that "SQLite is not particular about the text it receives and is more than happy to process text strings that are not normalized or even well-formed UTF-8. programmers who want to store IS08859 data can do..." Soo the text was originilally in ISO85(something)

Comment: I followed your advice and added a couple of utf8_encodes (thank you programming gods for OOP) so everything is utf8 from the start.

My main database has been recreated in UTF8, and I just added those line to couple my system with some plugin databases.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to use utf8_decode when retrieving data back. This is all only needed, if you use PHP's default charset (ISO-8859-1) internally. Consider using UTF-8 all through your system, in which case you don't have to encode anything (Yes, it's confusing).