# SQLite Charset / Character Encoding change in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, character-encoding, sqlite

I have some fancy characters (medical symbols) in sqlite database, `for eg: Aβ2M` but when I fetch records using [Codeigniter SQLite PDO Driver](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PDO_SQLite3/) the output result is `AÎ²2M`.

I read this article [How to change character encoding of a PDO/SQLite connection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263056/how-to-change-character-encoding-of-a-pdo-sqlite-connection-in-php) and tried `utf_decode` which results in this output `A?2M`

So how and what encoding should I set while fetching records to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is truly stored as UTF-8 in your database, declaring that charset (either on the page with a meta tag or an HTTP header) *should* be enough.

As long as you're just displaying the text, it's not particularly important that PHP "understands" what the characters actually are, but the browser *does* need to know the proper charset to interpret and correctly display the page. (Of course, if you start doing any processing on your strings in PHP, you'd need to make sure that you're using multibyte-aware functions and providing the correct charset there also).

`utf8_decode` won't help you here, since you're trying to show characters that aren't part of ISO 8859-1, the character set that function decodes to.