# Syntax Error for Creating Database in Python/SQL

Tags: python, sql, database

I want to create a table using the following:

```
def Create_Table():
c.execute("CREATE TABLE Interview_Test_Stat (
Employees VARCHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf8,
 VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf8,
 VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8,
 VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf8,
 INT,
Bosses VARCHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf8,
Column_7 VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8,
Column_8 VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8)"
)
```

But when I run it, i Get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Rony\Desktop\Tables.py", line 21, in Create_Table
c.execute("CREATE TABLE Interview_Test_Stat (Employees VARCHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf16, VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf16, VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf16, VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf16, INT,Bosses VARCHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf16, Column_7 VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf16, Column_8 VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf16)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "CHARACTER": syntax error
```

I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `2`,`3` and `4` column names missing

Comment: @sick answer should go as answers, not comments

Comment: @pgreen2 - There is nothing much to write one as answer.

Comment: @MM93 Thanks for the help. I added the names Column_2, 3 and 4 to the respective columns, but Unfortunately I get the same error message :(

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. It had to do with the 'character set utf8'. I decided to remove them from every column and continue from there.

Comment: SQLite seems to allow [character sets at the database and table level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263056/how-to-change-character-encoding-of-a-pdo-sqlite-connection-in-php) not individual table columns.