# Laravel eloquent not receiving accented characters from sqlite database

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel Eloquent to retrieve records from database. When I access string property of certain Eloquent model, it works perfectly as long as the string does not contain any accented character. Otherwise, I get some b-prefixed string literal full of strange characters. Such string passed to blade template does not render at all.

```
// Laravel dump
dump(Project::find(10)->title); // displays b"¬ernob¡lì svØt"
dump('Černobílý svět');        // displays "Černobílý svět" correctly

// Artisan tinker
>>> App\Project::find(10)->title
=> b"┬Černob┬íl├Č sv├śt"
```

However, when I access that record using sqlite command line, string looks fine. I guess this is a consequence of badly configured encoding but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
sqlite> select id, title from projects where id = 10
10 | Černobílý svět
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your header like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang='hr' class='no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7'> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang='hr' class='no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8'> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang='hr' class='no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9'> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang='hr' class='no-js lt-ie10'> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang='hr' class='no-js'> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Language' content='hr'>
```

Replace hr with your language code but save utf-8 as charset

Comment: This does not take any effect. I guess the problem is in PHP / Laravel rather than in HTML rendering, given the fact that artisan tinker returns incorrect string as well.

Comment: http://snag.gy/r1cfu.jpg
http://snag.gy/uu28G.jpg

As you see I'm unable to reproduce your issue...

Comment: You might want to check your database table collation and set it to utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I haven't found out how to do this with SQLite. Are you using SQLite too?

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263056/how-to-change-character-encoding-of-a-pdo-sqlite-connection-in-php

Comment: Ok, so my database is UTF-8. I have tried to call utf8_encode or utf8_decode (as is advised in the thread you sent me a link to) on strings with no success: the string looks same, only the "b" prefix disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **command line**. Records I have had problem with were added using Laravel's `php artisan tinker` trough eloquent model method `create()` or directly into database `sqlite3` shell, in both cases using console, which was probably the cause of character confusion. Thanks for help.